# How to connect VUE 3.x frontend websocket to DJANGO 4.x consumer using DJANGOCHANNELSRESTFRAMEWORK?

Tags: django-rest-framework, websocket, vuejs3, django-channels

I have a DJANGO project with the following files.

Basically I am using token authentication in my settings which works well for javascript fetch/axios since I can send the token in the headers. I use djoser to manage the token authentication; however when I try to run any custom action in my consumer.py file the user in self.scope.get('user') is always AnonymousUser and then it returns with an 'Not allowed' message.

Do I need to authenticate the user over websocket protocol?

Also worth noting. I am using DJANGOCHANNELSRESTFRAMEWORK and using DEMULTIPLEXER to handle the websocket/consumer routing.

UPDATE: I tried using using the 'list' action in my json data and in consumers.py I user permissions.AllowAny and it works as expected; however I still cannot use any of my own custom actions.

UPDATE 2: When using permissions.AllowAny I can actually use all my custom actions as well; however I'm not sure if this is safe. I would like for my user to be authenticated to do this through websocket in this DJANGO decoupled project.

SETTINGS.PY

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-=1l1i2&3mw2!5^zhchewl#ziv1=ip0i$jc+8n7ikryjufwsh9e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000','127.0.0.1:8000','127.0.0.1','http://localhost:8080','ws://localhost:8080']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
  'http://localhost:8080'
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'

    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ]
}


CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['http://127.0.0.1:8000','http://localhost:8080']


AUTH_USER_MODEL='users.User'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
    'corsheaders',
    'daphne',
    'channels',
    'users',
    'students',
    'instructors',
    'groups',
    'materials',
    'operation',
    'channels_demultiplexer',
]




MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # 'middleware.websocket_auth.TokenAuthMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]




ROOT_URLCONF = 'InterAct.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates/'),
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/','dist/','templates/'),
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'InterAct.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'InterAct.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True






MEDIA_URL='/media/'



# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
# STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'publick/static/')

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     BASE_DIR / "static",
#
# ]

# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

ASGI.PY

```
#ASGI config for InterAct project.

#It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

#For more information on this file, see
#https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/asgi/


import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from middleware.websocket_auth import TokenAuthMiddleware
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import operation.routing

from django.urls import re_path
from operation.consumers import DMultiplexer

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'InterAct.settings')

django_application = get_asgi_application()


application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_application,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            # TokenAuthMiddleware(URLRouter([

            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter([

                            # operation.routing.websocket_urlpatterns,
                            # re_path(r"^/$", DMultiplexer.as_asgi()),
                            re_path(r"^ws/$", DMultiplexer.as_asgi()),


                            ]))
        ),
    }
)
```

CONSUMERS.PY

```
from djangochannelsrestframework.generics import GenericAsyncAPIConsumer

from users.models import User
from users.serializers import UserSerializer
from channels.auth import login as channels_login
from django.contrib.auth import login




from instructors.models import Instructor
from instructors.serializers import InstructorSerializer

from groups.models import Group
from groups.serializers import GroupSerializer

from students.models import Student
from students.serializers import StudentSerializer


from djangochannelsrestframework.decorators import action
from djangochannelsrestframework.observer import model_observer
from djangochannelsrestframework import permissions
from djangochannelsrestframework.observer.generics import ObserverModelInstanceMixin
from djangochannelsrestframework.mixins import (
    ListModelMixin,
    RetrieveModelMixin,
    PatchModelMixin,
    UpdateModelMixin,
    CreateModelMixin,
    DeleteModelMixin,
)


from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

import secrets


class Instructors_Consumer(
        ListModelMixin,
        # RetrieveModelMixin,
        PatchModelMixin,
        UpdateModelMixin,
        CreateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        ObserverModelInstanceMixin,
        GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset=Instructor.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InstructorSerializer

    @action()
    async def subscribe_to_instructors_feed(self, request_id, **kwargs):
        print('are we all getting called?')
        await self.instructors_feed.subscribe(request_id=request_id)

    @model_observer(Instructor,serializer_class=InstructorSerializer)
    async def instructors_feed(self, data, action, subscribing_request_ids=[], **kwargs):
        # print(data,action,subscribing_request_ids)
        for request_id in subscribing_request_ids:
            await self.reply(data=data, action=action, request_id=request_id)

    @action()
    async def create_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data=kwargs.get('data')
        object=await self.create_model_db(data)
        return object,200

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_model_db(self,data):
        print(data)

        email=f'{secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)}@{secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)}.com'
        username=secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)

        new_user=User.objects.create(first_name='first_name',last_name='last_name',role="Instructor",email=email,username=username)

        new_instructor=new_user.instructor_set.first()

        new_instructor=InstructorSerializer(new_instructor).data
        print(new_user)
        print(new_instructor)

        return new_instructor




class Groups_Consumer(
        ListModelMixin,
        # RetrieveModelMixin,
        PatchModelMixin,
        UpdateModelMixin,
        CreateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        ObserverModelInstanceMixin,
        GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):

    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset=Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class=GroupSerializer


    @action(detail=False)
    async def subscribe_to_groups_feed(self, request_id, **kwargs):
        print('hello from another domain2222')
        print(request_id)
        print(dir(self))
        # [print(thing) for thing in dir(self)]
        print(self.scope.get('user'))
        # login(request, user) # <- This was missing

        await self.groups_feed.subscribe(request_id=request_id)

    @model_observer(Group,serializer_class=GroupSerializer)
    async def groups_feed(self, data, action, subscribing_request_ids=[], **kwargs):

        for request_id in subscribing_request_ids:
            await self.reply(data=data, action=action, request_id=request_id)
    @action()
    async def create_and_add_student(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data=kwargs.get('data')
        new_group=await self.create_and_add_student_db(data)
        return new_group,200

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_and_add_student_db(self,data):
        pk=int(data.get('pk'))
        group=Group.objects.get(pk=pk)

        email=f'{secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)}@{secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)}.com'
        username=secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)
        first_name=secrets.SystemRandom().randint(1,1000000)
        new_user=User.objects.create(first_name=first_name,role="Student",email=email,username=username)
        new_student=new_user.student_set.first()
        group.student.add(new_student)
        group.save()
        new_student=StudentSerializer(new_student).data

        response={
            'new_student':new_student,
            'parent':pk,
        }
        return response





class Students_Consumer(
        ListModelMixin,
        # RetrieveModelMixin,
        PatchModelMixin,
        UpdateModelMixin,
        CreateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        ObserverModelInstanceMixin,
        GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset=Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class=StudentSerializer

    @action()
    async def subscribe_to_students_feed(self, request_id, **kwargs):
        await self.students_feed.subscribe(request_id=request_id)

    @model_observer(Student,serializer_class=StudentSerializer)
    async def students_feed(self, data, action, subscribing_request_ids=[], **kwargs):
        # print(data,action,subscribing_request_ids)
        for request_id in subscribing_request_ids:
            await self.reply(data=data, action=action, request_id=request_id)





class Users_Consumer(
        ListModelMixin,
        # RetrieveModelMixin,
        PatchModelMixin,
        UpdateModelMixin,
        CreateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        ObserverModelInstanceMixin,
        GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):

    queryset=User.objects.all()
    serializer_class=UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    @action()
    async def subscribe_to_users_feed(self, request_id, **kwargs):
        print('hello from another domain')
        await self.users_feed.subscribe(request_id=request_id)

    @model_observer(User,serializer_class=UserSerializer)
    async def users_feed(self, data, action, subscribing_request_ids=[], **kwargs):
        # print(data,action,subscribing_request_ids)
        for request_id in subscribing_request_ids:
            await self.reply(data=data, action=action, request_id=request_id)





from channels_demultiplexer.demultiplexer import WebsocketDemultiplexer
class DMultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    consumer_classes={
        "users":Users_Consumer,
        "groups":Groups_Consumer,
        "instructors":Instructors_Consumer,
        "students":Students_Consumer,

    }
```

in my VUEX STORE index.js I have this action:

```
async openEndpoint(state,params){
  console.log(params);

  let ws=params.ws
  let endpoint=params.endpoint
  ws.onopen=async ()=>{
    console.log('connection established');

    console.log(endpoint);

    let data={
      stream:endpoint,
      payload:{
        action:'subscribe_to_groups_feed',
        request_id: new Date().getTime()
      }

    }
    console.log(ws);
    ws.onmessage=(ws_event)=>{
      let response=JSON.parse(ws_event.data)
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.payload.errors);
    }
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(data))


  }


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of researching it turns out that I can write middleware to incercept the websocket requests. I had to pass the token as a query_string parameter and then decode it in the middleware so that I could then get the user from the Token.objects provided by Djoser.

However now all my normal fetch requests are failing. I provide the Middleware for anyone trying to advance in this topic.

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddleware
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.sessions import CookieMiddleware, SessionMiddleware

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(scope_token):
    token = scope_token.decode('utf8')
    token= token.split('=')[1]
    print(token)
    if not token:
        return AnonymousUser()
    try:
        user = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
    except Exception as exception:
        return AnonymousUser()
    if not user.is_active:
        return AnonymousUser()
    return user


class TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, app):
        # Store the ASGI application we were passed
        self.app = app

async def __call__(self, scope,receive,send,*args,**kwargs):
    # Look up user from query string (you should also do things like
    # checking if it is a valid user ID, or if scope["user"] is already
    # populated).
    print('MIDDLEWARING')
    scope['user'] = await get_user(scope["query_string"])

    return await self.app(scope,receive,send)

async def resolve_scope(self, scope,receive,send):
    scope['user']._wrapped = await get_user(scope)
def TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
    return CookieMiddleware(SessionMiddleware(TokenAuthMiddleware(inner)))
```

UPDATE:
On applying the above solution I stopped being able to get my axios/fetch requests to work. I suppose this has to do with the fact that I used the middleware to intercept websocket requests. When I undo all the middleware changes everything works normal. The 'trick' around this was to just disable the middleware in settings.py somehow this allows the axios/fetch requests to go through django application normally and still incercepts the websocket requests. This is how the settings look like now.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'middleware.websocket_auth.TokenAuthMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: With this I can now use permissions.IsAuthenticated since the user is getting passed down through the scope['user']